# Transition from np.polyfit() to Polynomial - replacement for poly1d()?

Tags: python, numpy

As mentioned [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html) the `np.polyfit` should be replaced with `Polynomial` in new projects. There is also a transition guide. But there is some functionality of the older syntax that I don't know how to reproduce with the new one:

```
    p = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 5)
    p = np.poly1d(p)  # what to use with Polynomial instead?
    print(p(10))  # I want something like this
```

How can I do the same with the newer `Polynomial`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought I had tried it and it didn't work, but the solution is trivial:

```
p = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 5)
print(p(10))
```